# How long does it take for a item to despawn?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to know this because I died really far away and I am stressing that the items will despawn. My world tick speed is 1.

Comment: Um, this information is easily found online. Have you tried looking for answers yourself?

Comment: No, I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: 1? are you sure its 1?

Comment: Tick-speed 1 is Bedrock Edition's default

Comment: Welp my items despawned :( full neatherite  with mending elytra with mending unbreaking 3 neatherite pick and sword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_(entity)#Despawning

From the wiki:

> Items despawn after 6000 game ticks (**5 minutes**) of being in a loaded chunk. If two item stacks merge, the timer is set to the item that has more time remaining. The 5-minute timer is paused when the chunk is unloaded.